# Load a table of data using PHP and HTML, but I need a table at the top of a page to wait till it has data from the rest of the page

Tags: php, html

I have a web page that displays the status of multiple servers for administrators to glance at and know what's broken.  Management has decided they want to use the page too but it's too complicated and they just want a set of green or red lights at the top of the page so they do not have to think about the rest of the data unless they see a red light and then can look down the page.

The page pulls data from a SQLite database and displays the data down the page using tables.  I need to get a table at the top of the page to generate after the rest of the data is processed so as to tell it if a segment is green or red.

Is this possible just using HTML and PHP or am I needing to bring in something else like Javascript?

Comment: Lots of ways to do it, the easiest probably being to just iterate through the data twice -- i.e., once for each table. (Or maybe make two different pages, one "simple" and one "detailed", with the prior linking to the latter.)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Store the HTML for the bottom of the page in a variable so `$htm .= ......` rather than sending direct to the page, then you can also collect the staus info for your traffic lights. Send the traffic lights and then `echo $htm;`

Comment: A separate page would be easier, but they want one.  I was hoping to set a global variable as different functions processed, for example, if a drive is filling up and lights up red, I could set $driveStatus = 1; so if one drive or 14 drives come up as full it would be a 1 rather than a 0 and that top light would go red.  Have a separate global for drive, services, external connections, etc. all set to either 1 or 0.